# Find root cause of warning on all items as "This item contains broken links in: Tracking"

Tags: content-editor

We are getting the warning for `"This item contains broken links in: Tracking"` on all the items.
I have verified the "Tracking" field and its blank in raw values, still we are getting the warning.

Is there a way we can identify the root cause of this warning?

[image]

Sitecore version: `9.3`

`Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` is set to `false` on the environment.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the Links database?

Comment: Did you run the `Scan for database for broken links` report?

Comment: I have tried rebuilding the links database, still its the same. Also there are no mention of "Tracking" field in the items in the "Scan for database for broken links" report. Let me know, if there is anything else that could be verified.

Comment: Anything wrong with one of the versions of _Standard Values of that item template?

Comment: Check if there are any issues with the Experience Analytics Chart rendering in the Core database? That may also cause the issue.

Comment: The "Experience Analytics Chart" could not be rendered from "/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Dashboard" as Xdb is disabled. Let me know, if there is another way around.